# Get value from DIV element

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I want to pass a HTML element value to an Android application. I

I tried retrieving the value using the code below:

```
document.getElementById(\"summary\").value --> giving null value
document.getElementById(\"summary\").innerHtml --> giving null value
document.getElementById(\"summary\").textContent --> giving null value
```

I'm trying to implement javascript MutationObserver. So whenever there is a change in the content, I can immediately pass the value to the android java code.

Can anyone help me?

I used the following code:

```
    myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


     myWebView.loadUrl("https://helloworld.com/details");

    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this, myWebView), "MyHandler");
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        myWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }

    myWebView.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return document.getElementById(\"summary\").textContent})();",
            new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                   Log.e("HTML Content",html);
                }
            });
```

This is my HTML code:

```
 <div class="well" id="summary" *ngIf="viewModel != null">
    <div class="SuccessSummary">{{viewModel.successSummary}}</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that https://helloworld.com/details this domain contains this much HTML code?

Comment: helloworld I just gave as example, in the HTML page there are lot of codes. But I want value of SuccessSummary DIV to my Android application, that's my point. This value gets changed frequently

Comment: In that case, `MyHandler` should be added to the webpage. That key will send you responses whenever there's a change in value

Comment: This is my Javascript

<script type="text/javascript">
    /**
     * @return {string}
     */
    function MyHandler(){
      return document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML;
    }
    var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation);
      });
    });
    mutationObserver.observe(document.do, {
      attributes: true,
      characterData: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
      attributeOldValue: true,
      characterDataOldValue: true
    });
  </script>

Comment: In the above JavaScirpt, MutationObserver is working, but I want to get only the Summary values need to find way for that

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
myWebView.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return 
document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML})();",
        new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
               Log.e("HTML Content",html);
            }
        });
```

Comment: It's also giving null output